# Why is $\nabla \times (f(r) \vec r) = 0$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

With $r=\lvert \vec r\rvert$

I know how to work with $\nabla$ , but I don't know how to deal with $f(r) \vec r$ ... Can you help me?

Comment: Remember that $r=(x,y,z)$ and use change rule.

Comment: This is because $f(r)\vec{r} = \vec{\nabla}U(r)$ where $U(r) = \int^r f(s)s ds$

Comment: That is not necessary. We can do that problem with derivatives and no integrals.

Comment: what do you mean with change rule?

Comment: note that it is NOT $f(\vec r)r$ !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a computation. Try directly, as example I calculate the firt component:

$$(\nabla\times f(r)\vec r)_x= \displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(r)z-\displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial z}f(r)y $$

since

$$\displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(r)=f'(r)\displaystyle\frac{y}{r} $$

and similar

$$\displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial z}f(r)=f'(r)\displaystyle\frac{z}{r} $$

then

$$(\nabla f(r)\vec r)_x=f'(r)\displaystyle\frac{zy}{r}-f'(r)\displaystyle\frac{yz}{r}=0$$

In the same way you can compute the others components.

Comment: why is $$\displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(r)=f'(r)\displaystyle\frac{y}{r} $$ ?

Comment: Chain rule 
$$\displaystyle\frac{ \partial f(r)}{\partial y}=\displaystyle\frac{ df(r)}{dr}\displaystyle\frac{ \partial r}{\partial y} $$

Comment: what rule do you exactly use? I know the chain rule as $\frac{df(r)}{dy} = \frac{du}{dv} \frac{dv}{dy}$ ... and why is $\frac{\partial r}{\partial y } = \frac yr ?$

Comment: That is the chain rule in one variable.

Comment: Think $r=r(y)$, at moment you derive the others variables ($x,z$) remains constant.

Comment: $\displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial y} r=\displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial y} \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}=\displaystyle\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}} $

Traumatic, isn't it?