# How to calculate $\vec\nabla\times\frac{\vec{r}}{r^3}$ when $r$ can be $0$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I already know that $\vec\nabla\cdot\frac{\vec r}{r^3} = 4\pi\delta(\vec r)$. In that case, we calculate it directly when $r\neq 0$ and use Gauss' Law to prove it is equivalent to $4\pi\delta(\vec r)$. So I wonder how to calculate $\vec\nabla\times\frac{\vec r}{r^3}$ if we don't rule out the condition that $r$ may be zero?

Comment: $\vec\nabla\times\frac{\vec r}{r^3}$@Arashium

Comment: Is the question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1043518/why-is-nabla-times-fr-vec-r-0?rq=1 of use?

Comment: The expression $\frac{\vec r}{r^3}$ isn't defined for $r=0$. To put it into a one-dimensional case. You're asking something close to " what's $\frac{d}{dx} \frac{1}{x}$ if we dont suppose $x \neq 0$="

Comment: @Roland I just think that there is some similarity between $\nabla\cdot\frac{\vec r}{r^3}$ and $\nabla\times\frac{\vec r}{r^3}$. Now that we can use dirac delta function to descrip the former one, why cannot I apply a similiar method to the latter one? Of course I haven't found the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @jim. I add an answer.

Here,

$$\vec \nabla \times ({\vec r\over r^3})=\det{\begin{bmatrix}\hat a_x&\hat a_y&\hat a_z\\ \frac{\partial}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \\ {x\over r^3} & {y\over r^3} & {z\over r^3} \end{bmatrix}}$$

we know that

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}({y\over r^3})=y\frac{\partial}{\partial x}({1\over r^3})=y\frac{x}{r^3}$$

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}({x\over r^3})=x\frac{\partial}{\partial y}({1\over r^3})=x\frac{y}{r^3}$$

So, each of the cross multiplications used for the calculation of determinant give an equal results and the difference between them is zero. Hence, the entire determinant is zero:

$$\vec \nabla \times ({\vec r\over r^3})=\vec 0$$

---

I am an electrical engineer. If we look at it an a practical way, an [electric field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_field) has this form

$$E={q \over 4 \pi \epsilon_0}{ \vec r \over r^3}$$

when the charge $q$ is located in the origin.

To find the charge density at each location, we need [divergence](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/diverg.html):

$$\nabla.E={\rho \over \epsilon_0}$$

where $\rho$ is the density of charge.

In this case

$$\nabla.E={q \over 4 \pi \epsilon_0} 4 \pi \delta(\vec r)={q \delta(\vec r) \over \epsilon_0}$$ 
and $q \delta(\vec r)$ is equal to $\rho$

The stationary electric fields (unlike magnetic fields) are conservative. It means if a charge moves to another location and returns back to its original location regardless of the path, the applied potential energy is zero. In another term:

$$\vec \nabla \times E=\vec 0$$

Since:

$$\vec \nabla \times {\vec r\over r^3}=\vec 0$$

It is interesting to know that any vector field can be decomposed into two parts:

$$\vec V(x,y,z)=\vec D(x,y,z)+\vec C(x,y,z)$$

where $\vec \nabla \times \vec D = 0$ and $\nabla . C = 0$

---

**Update**

In addition, ${\vec r\over r^3}$ is gradient of a scalar field:

$${\vec r\over r^3}=\nabla {-1\over r}$$

[Curl of a gradient](http://mathinsight.org/curl_gradient_zero) of any scalar field is zero, thus:

$$\vec\nabla\times {\vec r\over r^3}=\vec\nabla\times \vec\nabla {-1\over r}=\vec 0$$

Comment: Thank you for your answering. But what I am concerned about is, what happens when r is near 0?

Comment: @HaroldH. The determinant is still zero.

Comment: @HaroldH. Please see my update too.